# How can I add a script to documentation pages in a Docusaurus theme?

Tags: javascript, themes, docusaurus

On a Docusaurus 2.x documentation site, I want to add a JavaScript as a .... Is there a plugin I can use, or what solution is there?

Even though I did not try anything yet, I am thinking about modifying the theme files in the @docusaurus folder in node_modules. However, this seems a bit unpractical.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can just add the script in the static directory and also put it in the docusaurus config: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/docusaurus-config#scripts

All static files will be served as `/<baseUrl>/<path-from-static-dir>`